# How to derive the allowed beta decay selection rule $\Delta L=0$?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, radioactivity

Starting from the beta decay matrix element and Fermi's golden rule how can one show that the matrix element at the leading order vanishes unless $\Delta L=0$?

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong, but I think this is basic kinematics and has nothing to do with fancy quantum mechanics. For a particle with mass $m$ and kinetic energy $E$, the nonrelativistic momentum is $p=\sqrt{2mE}$, whereas in the ultrarelativisic limit we have $p=E/c$. The nucleons are normally going to be nonrelativistic and the leptons ultrarelativistic. Assuming the energies to be of the same order of magnitude, say 1 MeV, we expect $p_\text{lepton}/p_\text{nucleon}\sim (1/c)\sqrt{E/2m}\sim 0.03$. So to a pretty good approximation, we're just replacing, say, a neutron with a proton in the same state of motion.

Answer (score 1):

Let the matrix element for $\beta$ decay from state $X$ to state $X^{\prime}$ be

$\cal{M}_{if}=g \langle (e^{i \vec{p}\cdot \vec{x}})(e^{i \vec{q}\cdot \vec{x}}) \psi_{x^{\prime}} \mid \cal{O_\beta} \mid \psi_x \rangle  $,

where $p$ and $q$ are momenta of electron and neutrino.

Electron and neutrino wavelengths ($\lambda$) are many times ($n$) size ($x$) of the nucleus  (  $\lambda \sim nx \sim 1/p$ so from this $px \sim x/(nx) \sim 1/n$ is small). So one can expand both plane waves in Taylor series $1 + \frac{i \vec{p} \cdot \vec{x}}{\hbar} + ... $ or better in Legendre polynomials with Bessel functions *(similar for neutrino with $q$)*

$ e^{i \vec{p} \vec{x} } = e^{ipx \cos(\theta)} = \Sigma_{l=0}^{\infty} i^l (2l+1)j_l(px) P_l( \cos(\theta) ) $

When only $L=0$ is present, the two $l=0$ terms of electron and neutrino naturally remain from the expansions, which are  $j_0(px) = \frac{ \sin(px)}{px}$, which for small $px$ goes to 1 *(the leading term)*.

The other pairs of $l_p=l_q>0$ that form together $L=0$ are of the next next order and together go to zero *(see the Bessel function systematics, but carefully about simple formulae)*.

[image]

The matrix element then turns into

$\cal{M}_{if} \sim g \langle  \psi_{x^{\prime}} \mid \cal{O_\beta} \mid \psi_x \rangle + g \langle  \psi_{x^{\prime}} \mid \cal{O_\beta} \mid \psi_x \rangle  {(px)(qx)} + ... $

which is the desired leading order part (for the Fermi superallowed decay $\psi_{x^{\prime}}$ and $\psi_{x}$ are virtually the same configurations, so the matrix element is like 1.)

**Now to the question :** if $\Delta L \ne 0$, the both plane waves with $l=0$ **cannot be present** at once and at least one term containing $px$ and/or $qx$ takes place. As seen in the picture, the Bessel functions other than $l=0$ go to zero. No term with ${kx}^0$ is thus present anymore.

Comment: Nice, +1! As far as I can tell, this is consistent with my simple kinematic argument. Does that seem right to you?

Comment: @BenCrowell thanks. Frankly, your kinematic argument is not very much clear to me. But this is possibly my fault. I just dont see the forbidden decays and various spin combinations of initial and final nuclear states in it.